# How to use Nant and MSBuild to build debug deployment

Tags: .net, asp.net, debugging, msbuild, nant

I have a **Nant** build script which referrences 30 other build scripts.

Each build script referrences a visual studio solution using **MSBuild**.

Each solution has 3 to 5 projects in.

Some projects are **Class Librarys** and some are **Web Apllications**.

The projects reference other projects both in their solution and out of their solution, so the projects do not use project references, **they reference the the Release DLLs in the Bin folders of the other projects**.

To use the software, I need to publish all the solutions together.

Which means I cannot do a deployment which is in debug mode.

Which means I cannot the step into and debug the code.

I would like to run the build script to get a deployment of the software which I can debug.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that it would be better to build and set the OutDir for all the build scripts

```
<property name="OutDir" value="${bin.output.dir}"/>
```

The get all the Projects to reference that location.

Then it does not matter if that are all debug or release.